# How to simplify this test if variable is "something"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

In node I want to test whether the variable i give to a function is "something". With that I mean not a `null` value or an empy array or empty object. So I wrote the following, which works as expected:

```
function f(v) {
    if (v === null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (v.constructor === Array) {
        if (v.length) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (v.constructor === Object) {
        if (Object.keys(v).length) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

f(null);  // false
f([]);  // false
f({}); // false
f([1]); // true
f({a: 1}); // true
```

This just seems horribly verbose. I presume there's an easier/simpler way of doing this. This is an option, but less readable and I think still too verbose:

```
function f(v) {
    if (v === null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (v.constructor === Array) {
        return !!v.length;
    }
    if (v.constructor === Object) {
        return !!Object.keys(v).length;
    }
}
```

I would expect it to be possible to reduce this to a one liner. Any idea how I would be able to do that?

Answer (score 8):

You can use only one condition as `v && Object.keys(v).length`. It works for `Array`, `Object`, `String` and `null` or `undefined` type.

```js
function f(v){
  v && Object.keys(v).length? console.log('true'): console.log('false');
}
f(null);  // Should be false
f([]);  // Should be false
f({}); // Should be false
f([1]); // Should be true
f({a: 1}); // Should be true
f(''); // Should be false
f('somename'); // Should be true
```

Comment: **Caveat for readers:** This might fail for old browsers. `Array.length` used to be an enumerable property. Modern browsers have removed it. Hence even `for..in` can be used on arrays.

Comment: @Rajesh comment from you was expected. Thanks for that knowledge

Comment: Not sure if I should take it as a compliment or criticism. Nonetheless, its more of a caveat for readers. Not asking you to change anything

Answer (score 3):

You could return a boolean value of the check of the object.

```js
function f(o) {
    return Boolean(o && typeof o === 'object' && Object.keys(o).length);
}

console.log(f(null));     // false
console.log(f([]));       // false
console.log(f({}));       // false
console.log(f([1]));      // true
console.log(f({ a: 1 })); // true
```